# Tensorflow 2 Tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow

Currently getting the below error with my tensor when utilising Tensorflow 2:

> tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 8) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 8), dtype=tf.float32,
> name='dense_input'), name='dense_input', description="created by layer
> 'dense_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape
> (None, 1, 8).

Just wondering on how I'd reshape it to get a shape of None,8 instead of None, 1, 8. I've used tf.reshape before but I'm unsure how to use it in this circumstance.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/squeeze

`tf.squeeze(input)` will remove all axes of size 1

or

`tf.squeeze(input, 1)` will remove only the 1st axis from input